# How can I define the order for a code snippet?

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

I'm trying to ask a CSS-related question with some demo code. I have some JavaScript there which is not directly related to the problem and is only used to toggle some dynamic state so that the problem can be demonstrated better.

But the snippet is displayed with JavaScript being first. I think this may be distracting to the reader. Is there a way to define which code block comes first, CSS, HTML or JavaScript?

Comment: No but there is an option to "collapse" the code snippet to just a button/link to reduce the size of the appearance on the page. "Hide snippet by default" - It's often below the fold of the screen so you have to scroll down to find it.

Comment: > Does this answer your question? 
-- 
But there's no solution as far as I can tell, it's just another request

Comment: There is no current "solution" other than the "Hide Snippet" option. Anything else has either been not taken up or rejected by the devs.

Comment: @Paulie_D that feature request is completely different, it asks about hiding certain sections of the snippet rather than ordering them. I don't really agree with closing this as a duplicate of that.

Comment: Effectively the same thing, hiding/re-ordering is just de-emphasising one element of the snippet. It's not a functionality that is essential or even, IMO, required because one type of code is "distracting" to a very small subset of viewers.

Comment: @Paulie_D "_Effectively the same thing_" not really they are two different requests. "_It's not a functionality that is essential or even, IMO, required_" that's not a closure reason, nor does it mean a question is a duplicate. Downvote the post if you feel the feature is unnecessary, or post an answer that disagrees with the feature request.